# Inserting DOM element while page is loading, not afterwards

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension, that inserts a div into the body element of the dom. Right now I am creating an event handler that fires on load to create the element. This means of course that the page loads completely, and then my div is inserted, which means the user sees the page without the div until loading is complete, and then the div pops up. I would like the div to be there while the page is loading. Is there a way to hijack the body element before any other elements have been written? Or do I have to somehow hide the content until everything has loaded, which of course would mean that the user sees a blank screen for a while.

If at all possible, I would like to avoid jQuery.

Comment: Use "run_at": "document_end" will guarantee that the div is injected *as early as possible* , though it does NOT guarantee that users won't see this change in DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but looking at the Chrome extension developer guide, it looks like if you are using a Content Script and specify the `run_at` field in your extension's manifest as `document_start`, then it should inject the files before the DOM is constructed.

Comment: Correct. Note: at document_start, `document.body does not exists yet. You have to inject using `document.documentElement.appendChild(element);`

Comment: @RobW, so the injected `div` will be placed outside `body`? This seems like incorrect html.

Comment: @Stan At document_start, the only existing tag is `<html>`, so it's the only option. And I haven't encountered a page where this method failed.

Comment: @RobW, yes I know, this is why I'm asking how the `div` will "live" outside the `body`, as a separate child of the `html`? I admit that the `div` is actually inserted, but I'm not sure how it's rendered and otherwise processed by modern browsers.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but can't get it to work with my div, which, if I am not mistaken, HAS to live in the body part for the following reason: The div I am creating is "fullscreen" and disabels scrolling, which I achieve by setting a style attribute on body (`overflow:hidden`) and one on the div (`width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;top:'+document.body.scrollTop+';z-index:1000'`). I tried setting all that on document.documentElement without success. I know I didn't make that exactly explicit in the original question. Should I add that? Not sure of the etiquette here.